# Need Advice with the dax in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

Attached is the image of data :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYc0u.png)

```
column [TRIP] having 'One Side' value the [Count of travel] should be divided by 2, basically
when [TRIP] = 'One Side' then [Count of travel]/2 
if [TRIP] ='Return' then No change in [Count Of Travel]
if [TRIP] = 'NA' then No change in [Count Of Travel].
the measure is working fine for the value 'One Side' but for 'Return' and 'NA' showing blank values or different number which is not in as [Count of travel]
DAX used is : 

    
    Measure = CALCULATE(DIVIDE([Count of travel],2),'Details'[TRIP] = "OneSide")

     

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gWkR.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a measure but a new Column

```
Expected Result = 
var tripType = mytable[TRIP]
var tripCount = mytable[Count of Travel] 
return if (tripType = "One Side", tripCount/2, tripCount)
```

Measures are calculated based on your result set in your visual. Columns are "static" precalculated values.